# Can't find the error in my Haskell code

Tags: haskell, river-crossing-puzzle

I tried to translate a (working !) solution of the cabbage-goat-wolf puzzle from Scala to Haskell, but the code throws and error when calling `head` in `findSolutions` because the solution list is empty, so the problem seems to be somewhere in loop. `findMoves` seems to work fine.

```
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

data Item = Farmer | Cabbage | Goat | Wolf deriving (Eq, Show)

type Position = ([Item], [Item]) 

validPos :: Position -> Bool
validPos p = valid (fst p) && valid (snd p) where   
   valid list = elem Farmer list || notElem Goat list || 
                (notElem Cabbage list && notElem Wolf list) 

findMoves :: Position -> [Position]
findMoves (left,right) = filter validPos moves where
    moves | elem Farmer left = map (\item -> (delItem item left, addItem item right)) left 
          | otherwise = map (\item -> (addItem item left, delItem item right)) right
    delItem item = filter (\i ->  notElem i [item, Farmer]) 
    addItem Farmer list = Farmer:list      
    addItem item list = Farmer:item:list      

findSolution :: Position -> Position -> [Position]
findSolution from to = head $ loop [[from]] where
    loop pps = do
          (p:ps) <- pps
          let moves = filter (\x -> notElem x (p:ps)) $ findMoves p
          if elem to moves then return $ reverse (to:p:ps)
                           else loop $ map (:p:ps) moves  

solve :: [Position]
solve = let all = [Farmer, Cabbage, Goat, Wolf]
        in findSolution (all,[]) ([],all)
```

Of course I would also appreciate hints concerning improvements not related to the actual error.

**[Update]**

Just for the record, I followed the suggestion to use a `Set`. Here is the working code:

```
import Data.Set

data Item = Farmer | Cabbage | Goat | Wolf deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type Position = (Set Item, Set Item)

validPos :: Position -> Bool
validPos p = valid (fst p) && valid (snd p) where
   valid set = or [Farmer `member` set, Goat `notMember` set, 
                   Cabbage `notMember` set && Wolf `notMember` set]

findMoves :: Position -> [Position]
findMoves (left,right) = elems $ Data.Set.filter validPos moves where
    moves | Farmer `member` left = Data.Set.map (move delItem addItem) left
          | otherwise = Data.Set.map (move addItem delItem) right
    move f1 f2 item = (f1 item left, f2 item right)
    delItem item = delete Farmer . delete item 
    addItem item = insert Farmer . insert item 

findSolution :: Position -> Position -> [Position]
findSolution from to = head $ loop [[from]] where
    loop pps = do
          ps <- pps
          let moves = Prelude.filter (\x -> notElem x ps) $ findMoves $ head ps
          if to `elem` moves then return $ reverse $ to:ps
                             else loop $ fmap (:ps) moves

solve :: [Position]
solve = let all = fromList [Farmer, Cabbage, Goat, Wolf]
        in findSolution (all, empty) (empty, all)
```

The call to `head` in `findSolution` could be made safer, and a better way to print out the solution should be used, but apart from that I'm quite happy with it.

**[Update 2]**

I think the former representations of the positions were suboptimal for this kind of problem. I switched to the following data model, which made moving etc slightly more verbose, but *much* more readable:

```
data Place = Here | There deriving (Eq, Show)

data Pos = Pos { cabbage :: Place
               , goat :: Place
               , wolf :: Place
               , farmer :: Place 
               } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: Instead of using `head` and `loop` try to use pattern matching and recursion.

Comment: I agree that the error handling could be nicer, but the problem remains that there **is** a solution, so the list returned by loop shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `[Farmer,Goat,Cabbage,Wolf]` is not the same that `[Farmer,Cabbage,Goat,Wolf]` and you don't check it when use `elem` and `notElem`. One solution is always sort the list of elements, e.g in the function `findMoves` you can use:

```
import Data.List(ord)
import Control.Arrow((***))

data Item = Farmer | Cabbage | Goat | Wolf deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

findMoves (left,right) = map (sort***sort) $ filter validPos moves where
-- ....

solve = let all = sort [Farmer, Cabbage, Goat, Wolf]
-- ....
```

Or you can use a set of Item instead a list of Item.

Comment: Oh my god, this is embarrassing! The original code used a set, but I thought I could get away with a list. Thank you so much!